# Stop user using email verification link more than once. PDO prepared statement not functioning

Tags: php, email, pdo, repeat, verification

EDIT: based on first reply I got below,I reworked my code and it now works... first checking the given email address to find the gamer id. Then checking the verfication state based on the gamer id. So if they change their email address in the future it will still know whether it's already been verified.

Below is my final code, (I've changed some name for items, so its not an exact copy/paste of my own code).

```
function email_not_verified ($email) { //check it's not already verified
include ('../connect.php'); // Include connect to database functions
$findUser= $db->prepare("SELECT game_id FROM players WHERE email=?");
$findUser->execute(array($email));
$user = $findUser->fetch();

if ( $findUser){
$veri= $db->prepare("SELECT sent_verification FROM players WHERE game_id=?");
$veri->execute(array($user["game_id"]));
$results = $veri->fetch();
$final = $results["sent_verification"];
}

if ($final == 1){
return TRUE;
}
else{
    return FALSE;
}   
}
```

Thanks again for the help.

Below, is my original question.

I'm trying to figure out a simple setup that stops a user repeatedly verifying their email address. As when they verify their email I'm awarding them a bonus of 300 credits for in store game purchases. I obviously don't want to keep dishing that out each time they follow their emailed verification link.

So I'm trying to run a check first, before the normal verification script is run.

*But surprise, surprise: its not working...*

I was trying to search my database for the email address with the verification field set to '1', I'd then see how many times it found this result. If it found it '0' times then that's fine to verify, if it found it once then its already been verified before.

```
function email_not_verified ($email) {
include ('../connect.php'); // connect to database 
//check it's not already verified
$checkEmail= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE sent_verification=?, email=?");
$checkEmail->execute(array('1', $email));   

$check2 = $checkEmail->rowCount();

if ($check2 = 1){
return TRUE;
}
else{
    return FALSE;
}

}
```

I've been using

```
 file_put_contents('results.txt',$check2);
```

to see the results of the code regardless of whether its putting out a TRUE or FALSE. But the result comes back as '0', even though I can see from looking at my database it should be '1'.

I'm not sure if there's a whole easier way to approach this, I keep trying to get my head around bind values but it's not yet sinking in... I'll continue to try.

Thanks for any help, guidance, pointing out the obvious... I feel like I've taken the wrong path with my script but can't think how else to approach it...

Cheers

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is wrong.  You're using the assignment operator instead of comparison.  This doesn't matter though because rowCount isn't always reliable, which is probably where the actual problem is.  What you need to do is fetch the first row and see if you get a row back.

However, you probably don't want to attach this to e-mail verification.  When users change their e-mail address, you will want to verify that new address and you probably don't want to give them 300 more credits each time they do.  Otherwise, someone could programmatically change their e-mail address over and over again, creating a lot of credits for themselves.

I would separate out the 300 free credits as a coupon or something that can only be used once per account.  On e-mail verification, if that coupon hasn't already been used up for that account, use it and mark it as such in your database.  This could be done simply by adding another column for new_account_bonus_credits or something.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So if I use something like == or > where I've previously just used = that should sort that out...  and I'll give using fetch a go (I had used it earlier but hit another problem, and kept adapting my code till I arrived at the above). Also yep, your 110% right, I should'nt be checking it against their email. I'll rework it so if finds the persons userid based on the given email, and then check the verification status based on the userid... thanks for the help. Jon

Comment: Thanks again for the help.. I've updated my original question with my final and working code.